# How to configure Test Result Analyzer plugin on Jenkins

Tags: testng, jenkins-plugins

I installed Test Result Analyzer plugin in Jenkins but getting message: `No build data retrieved. You may need to select a Module.`

After the plugin is installed - what are my next steps to get it working?

Is it necessary to enable "Publish TestNG results" plugin?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have faced this problem since yesterday too. I think the problem is that test analyzer cannot find data to report. And below is what I did to solve it

- At Jenkins dashboard, select `<your project>` / Configure
- Under **Post-build Actions** tab, select **Add post-build action** and choose **Publish JUnit test result report**
- At **Test report XMLs**, enter the path to your .xml report file, the analyzer will find data here to create charts, in my case, it's **app/build/test-results/prodDebug/*.xml**, you can edit the path to handle more tests.

And now, when you click **Test Results Analyzer**, the magic will appear xD

Good luck!

Comment: thanks. After i added post -build action Publish TestNG results - Test Analyzer started to show reports.

Comment: But I don't know what to write inside the test report XMLs.

Comment: If I don't have `.xml` file then what would be the path and how to create the file. 
For me i am doing `**/*.xml` and it says
`‘**/*.xml’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*.xml’`
Please help