# Jenkins Test Result Analyzer doesn't display results

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins

I have been using jenkins' TRA plugin for a while and all of a sudden it stopped showing results for some of the jobs I'm running. The message, which I'm getting:

> No build data retrieved. You may need to select a Module.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469654/how-to-configure-test-result-analyzer-plugin-on-jenkins/39502401#39502401) answer but I'm already using **Publish JUnit test result report** under **Post-build Actions**.

Job's workspace path is correct, all of the test report .xml files are there.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you show your jenkins job ?

Comment: @FranckCussac This is how it's configured: [JUnit Configuration](https://i.imgur.com/6iXfUDM.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

> No build data retrieved. You may need to select a Module.

What this means depends somewhat on the kind of Jenkins project you're dealing with.  It also seems to be the only error message the plugin has, which makes deciphering it more difficult than it should be.

This question appears to be about about a Freestyle job (as opposed to a Maven job), since the *Publish JUnit test result* post-build action is mentioned.

**Freestyle Job**

With a freestyle job, this error typically means that the *published* XML file (or series of *published* XML files) isn't found.  "Selecting a Module" doesn't make any sense in this context.

When you publish JUnit results, the xml files in your workspace are processed into a single file, called `junitResult.xml`.  This is what I mean when I refer to the *published* XML file.  This file is stored outside of the workspace, in the build history:

```
D:.                                   
└───jobs                              
    └───MavenFreestyle                
        ├───builds                    
        │   ├───1                     
        │   │       build.xml         
        │   │       changelog.xml     
        │   │       junitResult.xml   
        │   │       log               
        │   │                         
        │   └───2                     
        │           build.xml         
        │           changelog.xml     
        │           junitResult.xml   
        │           log               
        │                             
        └───workspace                 
            │   pom.xml               
            │                         
            ├───.mvn                  
            ├───src                   
            └───target
```

If these `junitResult.xml` files are missing, you'll get empty TRA results.  Of course, if no test results are found in the workspace, no `junitResult.xml` files will ever get created.  I suppose it's also at least possible that they're being created, but then modified or deleted by some process or person.

At any rate, *these* are the files whose existence (and contents) you want to verify, more than anything in the workspace.

If these `junitResult.xml` files appear to be in place for your jobs with empty results, updating the question with the contents of one of them would be helpful.

---

To verify files are found in the workspace to publish, make sure this check box is unchecked:

[image: Fail on empty test results]

This way, if there *is* a mismatch between your Ant pattern and your actual file locations, the build will fail.  If this box is checked, and you fat finger your include pattern, the job will succeed but your TRA results will be empty.

**Maven Job**

For readers running into this using Maven Jobs:

Here, "select a Module" does make sense.  The Test Results Analyzer link works from a `Module` page, but shows blank results when accessed from a `Project` page.

I found [this "documentation" of said behavior](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin?focusedCommentId=97091597#comment-97091597) buried in the comments of the plugin wiki page.

[image: Maven Project page]

[image: Maven Module page]

**Multi-configuration job**

With a Multi-configuration project, you must access the results via a `Configuration` page.  Accessing them from the `Project` page always yields empty results.

[image: Multi-configuration project page]

[image: Multi-configuration Configuration page]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! However, it looks like the junitResult.xml files are properly generated and in place...

Comment: My job is actually a **MultiJob Project**, does it make any difference?

Comment: Does MultiJob == Multi-configuration?  For a Multi-configuration project, there is a similar "gotcha" as with a Maven project.  That is, you have to click _Test Results Analyzer_ from a *Configuration* page.  Accessing the results from the *Project* page always shows empty results.  The message says "select a module", but a better message might say "select a configuration".

Comment: Hi @MikePatrick, MultiJob != Multi-configuration, Multijob refers to [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)